# Git push all updates from one repo to another

Tags: git

I have forked project X on Github, and it is checked out on my machine.

I have cloned my github project, and I have two remotes: origin (my fork) 
and parent (parent repo).

I will be adding new branches to origin, but not touching existing branches
forked from parent.

I have a cron job that runs nightly; I would like to fetch all changes from parent
and push all changes to origin, so that I keep up to date with parent.

Currently, I run

```
git fetch --all
git push --all
```

Will this be sufficient to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Git fetch and git push will only effect origin and git fetch will only effect tracking branches leading to the git push failing when the origin changes

Comment: actually, git fetch --all fetches from all remotes. So, I think I am good there. But git push is what I am not sure about

Comment: `git push origin --all` would push to _only_ your "my fork" if you are looking for a way to push to only one repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git push origin --all` would push all branches from your local repo to *only* your "my fork" repo.